# Can't access the nested objects but can render the non-nested ones from API (using React hooks)

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

I'm a bit stumped on this problem I encountered trying to render the data from an API. Weird thing is I successfully fetched the data and I can render the values of properties in the array but the moment it becomes a nested property within an array it returns undefined. Do you by any chance know why?

```
        location[0] + '&lon=' + 
        location[1] + '&APPID=8e6150cf719d58fc8062d507eaba92c0'

    const [data, loading] = useFetch(url);

    console.log(data.main.temp) // returns undefined
    console.log(data.name) // logs name
```

The useFetch() is the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchUrl() {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
        setLoading(false);
      }

    fetchUrl();
  }, [url]);
  return [data, loading];
}
export { useFetch };
```

The error message is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Data fetched looks like this:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 2.18,
        "lat": 41.42
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 293.81,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "humidity": 77,
        "temp_min": 292.04,
        "temp_max": 294.82
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.6,
        "deg": 120
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1561061585,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 6414,
        "message": 0.0074,
        "country": "ES",
        "sunrise": 1561004254,
        "sunset": 1561058875
    },
    "timezone": 7200,
    "id": 3124932,
    "name": "el Clot",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: can you post what the data looks like and also your component? and until the request is finished you wont have the data, so something being undefined may just be you're waiting for the deferred to resolve

Comment: In your component, are you calling `console.log` right after the useFetch line like your snippet above?

Comment: Hi John! Yes, just added the data fetched. Would it be for the unnested ones to show in console but for the nested ones to not do so? Also tried conditional rendering but same thing. Yes, indeed. Calling it after the useFetch.

Comment: so a fetch request is a promise, it needs time to resolve. you should wait for the data to come before trying to console.log

Comment: What i mean is [**something like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usefetch-bhqm0). Don't try to `console.log` until you have the data loaded

Comment: Could you post the code for useFetch too (or a reference to the package you are using)? The final value of `data` depends on how the hook is actually implemented.

Comment: I just posted the useFetch, Jeremy. Thanks, John. I'll try it out and I'll let you know if changing it works.

Comment: @AllynAlda This could be caused because `data.main` at the first instance is `undefined`. Try changing your console.log to: `console.log(!!data.main ? data.main.temp : 'not fetched yet')`

Comment: @LiJonas Indeed, the first render shows 'not fetched yet'. I though conditional rendering through checking if loading would solve this issue. How can I do conditional rendering based on data.main.temp already exists or not?

Comment: Your should add the full component that tries to render the data

Comment: @AllynAlda In your component before your main return statement you can write `if (!data || !data.main || loading) return null;` (or some kind of spinner/loader instead of null)